# Resize and center image in html/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way I can resize, crop, and center an image using html/css only? (img tag or css sprite)

For example if I have a 500x500 pixel image,

1. I want to resize that to a 250x250 pixel image
2. I want to make the actual visible image to be 100x100, but still have the scale of a 250x250 sized image.
3. I want the center of the image to be at a location x,y.

Is that possible with only html/css, if not, how do you propose I go about it with javascript?

Edit - 動靜能量:

For (2), say my scaled image is now 200x200, and I want my visible image to be 100x100: So I guess what I mean is I want the scale and resolution of the image to be 200x200 but I want the visible image to be 100x100 or in other words the visible image would be at coordinates x,y: 0,0; 0,100; 100,0; 100,100; of the 200x200 image. Sorry, but I'm not good at explaining this.

Comment: for (2), do you mean it is cropped?  250 x 250 after the resize, but showing only 100 x 100 pixels of that image

Comment: you can not crop image by html/css

Comment: may be possible with overflow:hidden-ed block element over it

Comment: or you can try making a div with a size of 100x100 and put the img as background and put background: url(img250x250 path) center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: an example at** http://jsfiddle.net/LTrqq/5/

For

1. You can just use CSS's `width` and `height` for the `<img>` element
2. It can be done by (1), and place this image into a div, and `position: absolute`, with a desired `top` and `left`, and place it in another div with `position: relative`, and this outer div can have `width: 100px`, `height: 100px`, and `overflow: hidden`
3. same as (2), with the desired `top` and `left` value.

We need the `position: relative` for the outer div in (2), because we want the inner div to position relative to this outer div, rather than relative to the whole document.

For the `top` and `left`, it is like `top: -50px; left: -50px` as an example.

Comment: cool, i think this is what I'm looking for, and thx for the demo.  However, if I don't know the dimensions of the image beforehand to calculate the center of the image, will I have to javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Just done this off the top off my head but it should be nearly there if not completely accurate. The -X and -Y coordinates are what get you to the crop offset. So for example if you want to crop from 20x30 you'd make them -20px and -30px.

```
<style>
    #crop { width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
    #crop img { position: absolute; left: -X; top: -Y; }
</style>

<div id="crop">
    <img src="500x500.jpg" width="250" height="250">
</div>
```

If you want to center it though and you know the size of the image in the crop container you could use the following CSS instead:

```
#crop img { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin: -125px 0 0 -125px; }
```

125px is half of 250 so it should make it central.

Answer (score 0):

You can definatley size the image to any dimenson then place it in a div and hide the overflow to acheive a crop look. However if you actually want to crop the image so that say someone wants to download a copy of it cropped and scaled check out: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

But if you can at all try PHP, http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/
is very easy to use, just put it on your server and point your img tag src to it.
example: < img src="/timthumb.php?mycat.jpg&h=250&w=250" />